# jQuery .live("click", fn) works only on second click

Tags: jquery, event-binding

I have a DOM element that is generated with js, and therefore when i want to bind a click event            listener i need to use `$(generatedEl).live("click", fn...)` (is there a different way?)

here is the code i am using:

```
$(".toggleView").live("click", function(){
                    if(isTrunced){
                        $(this).html(cntarctText).siblings("h3").html(currEl.data("md").myFullText)
                        isTrunced = false
                    }
                    else{
                        $(this).html(expandText).siblings("h3").html(currEl.data("md").truncedText)
                        isTrunced = true
                        }       
                     });
```

(this is in middle of a `.each()`)

But the function only runs on the second click.

can someone please help me track down this weird bug,
Thanks

EDIT: Added the entire code block.

```
    var truncMe = function(passedNode, passedChanges){
        var truncTarget = passedNode,
            expandText = "more",
            cntarctText = "less",
            isTooLong = false,
            isTrunced = false,
            maxChar = 170,
            toggleView


            truncTarget.each(function (index, domEle) {
            var currEl = $(domEle)


            currEl.data("md", {myFullText:currEl.html(),isTooLong:false, isTrunced:false })
                if(currEl.data("md").myFullText.length >= maxChar){
                    currEl.data("md").truncedText = currEl.data("md").myFullText.substring(0, maxChar);
                    currEl.data("md").isTooLong = true;
                    currEl.siblings(".toggleView").remove()
                    if(passedChanges){
                        currEl.data("md").myFullText = passedChanges;
                        currEl.data("md").truncedText = currEl.data("md").myFullText.substring(0, maxChar);
                    }
          /* here the element is created */
                    toggleView = $("<div class='toggleView'/>").html(expandText).appendTo(currEl.parent()); 
                    currEl.html(currEl.data("md").truncedText)
          /* here the event is binded */                        
$(".toggleView").live("click", function(){

                    if(isTrunced){
                        $(this).html(cntarctText).siblings("h3").html(currEl.data("md").myFullText)
                        isTrunced = false
                    }
                    else{
                        $(this).html(expandText).siblings("h3").html(currEl.data("md").truncedText)
                        isTrunced = true
                        }       
                     });        
                }
                else{
                    currEl.siblings(".toggleView").remove()

                    }
             });                                                        

        }
```

Comment: This entire code snippet is inside an $.each()?  Each what?  Why would you need to run this statement more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The great thing about `.live()` is that it doesnt need to be called more than once. All you have to do is take it out of the `.each()`.

Since you are using a class as a selector any element that you will create with that class will automatically be bound to the click event.

Comment: thanks, but nope.  i removed it outside of the each and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the variable "isTrunced" needs to be extracted from the data. Since it isn't defined initally (inside the live function) it will default to false.

So once you pull the live function out of the each loop, try this:

```
$(".toggleView").live("click", function(){
 if($(this).data("isTrunced")){
  $(this).html(cntarctText).siblings("h3").html(currEl.data("md").myFullText)
  $(this).data("isTrunced", "false");
 } else {
  $(this).html(expandText).siblings("h3").html(currEl.data("md").truncedText)
  $(this).data("isTrunced", "true");
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, i got the problem

the logic of the if was buggy.

This is the corrected:

```
if(isTrunced){
  $(this).html(cntarctText).siblings("h3").html(currEl.data("md").myFullText)
  isTrunced = false
    }
else{
 $(this).html(expandText).siblings("h3").html(currEl.data("md").truncedText)
   isTrunced = true
  }
```

Anyway thanks to [Ariel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130434/ariel), good point.

Comment: @adardesign: If Ariel answered your question, you should accept the answer provided.

Comment: Ok, thanks...

Looks like the community @ SO is caring each for the other :)